# Namespace names not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The 'using' part at the beginning of the c# code isn't showing up as working in visual studios, but the code itself works in unity 2019.1.5f1

This is using Unity 2019.1.5f1 and visual studios for mac with mono 6.0.0.293. I reinstalled visual studios for mac and unity. Other solutions were locked to previous versions and windows visual studios

```
...
using UnityEngine;
Public class behaviourscript; monobehaviour
...
```

I expect the code in visual studios to use the things I type after 'using' However, it just has this message when I hover over the error it says,

"Error: the type or namespace name 'UnityEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Try to Unload and Reload your project.

Comment: click on packages and hit re import all

Comment: I guess the rest are just typos right? (`Public` should be `public`, `;` should be `:` and `monobehaviour` should be `MonoBehaviour`). How do you open the script? It will only work doubleclicking it within Unity in the `ProjectView` or on the GameObject it is attached to. Don't open the script from your FileBrowser

Answer (score 0):

how are you opening the scripts? from the file explorer or from Unity? if you're opening from the file explorer, you are just opening a single file and not the whole project/resolution, and that can be the reason why its giving this error.

if that doesn't work, try re-importing the packages.